# HTMLUnit thinks Submit Button is a text input

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am attempting to process a form in Java with HtmlUnit. It works fine until it tries to find and click the submit button.

Here is what the form looks like,

```
<form method="get" action="result.php">
    <p>Text: <input type="text" name="text"/></p>
    <p>Agree: <input type="checkbox" name="doYouAgree" value="agree" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

I've searched around a tried many different methods for retrieving the element but it consistently returns HtmlTextInput rather than HtmlSubmitInput.

```
form.getInputByName("Submit").click();
```

I've also tried processing a form with every type of input and no matter the type it always returns HtmlTextInput.

Has anyone seen this issue or know how to correct it? I'm concerned that this is the reason why HtmlUnit is not submitting any forms.

Comment: Have you tried using the `button` tag?

Comment: Yeah and it still returns it as HtmlTextInput.

Comment: Can you not just cast it to `HtmlSubmitInput`?

Comment: No it causes a ClassCastException :-(

Comment: I don't know the HtmlUnit API (I usually use it via Geb), but I suspect `getInputByName` isn't the right method to be calling for something that's not technically an input.

Comment: Well, the Submit button is an input `<input type="submit" ... />` and from debugging their code the `HtmlSubmitInput` class does search for the `input` tag. What's really annoying is that `HtmlSubmitInput`, `HtmlButtonInput`, and `HtmlImageInput` are the only classes that will actually submit a form when clicked on. Unless I'm able to figure out how to get `HtmlSubmitInput` returned then it doesn't look like the form will be submitted.

Comment: With latest version 2.18, I am seeing `HtmlSubmitInput`, please provide minimal HTML and Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit a form with a base object, as DomElement.

```
DomElement button = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@name='Submit']");
HtmlPage new_page = button.click(); // or you can use the old page
```

should work.

Comment: Some code we were reusing from an older system wasn't ported over correctly which is what was causing the problem. Thanks for the answer though, it isn't something I had seen when searching for a solution so I'm selecting this as the answer.